# math min and max returns NaN

Tags: javascript, math

I want to log the min and max number from an array of numbers, that keep changing on runtime.
I am using ES5 `Math.min` and `Math.max`. I even clone the input array to avoid concurrent changes. This is my code:

```
var runTimes = input.runTimes.slice(0); // clone input to avoid further changes
console.log("RUN TIMES", runTimes);
var min = Math.min(runTimes);
var max = Math.max(runTimes);
console.log("RUN TIMES MIN", min);
console.log("RUN TIMES MAX", max);
```

I get `NaN` even though all items are numbers, verified by the log:
[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min Read the documentation's demo on its usage

Comment: [Search results for "Math.max NaN"](https://www.google.com/search?q=math.max+nan+site%3AStackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.min` or `Math.max` do not expect array but distinct numbers.
Please try this:

```
var min = Math.min(...runTimes);
var max = Math.max(...runTimes);
```